# Webpack Manifest Hashing - Vendor not being hashed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have been following the tutorials [here](http://madole.xyz/asset-hashing-with-webpack/) and on this [medium blog](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95#.ylv8v4oj1) and their output always gets hashed so it's like `bundle-18734678.js` and `vendor-32422342.js` - my bundle is hashed but for some reason the vendor doesn't get hashed at all. The image below shows just `vendor.js`.

[image]

My webpack file is below.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');

const vendorPackages = [
  'react', 
  'react-router', 
  'react-redux', 
  'toastr', 
  'lodash'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: [ './src/index.js' ],
    vendor: vendorPackages
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/prod'),
    publicPath: '/dist/prod',
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash:8].js'
  }, 

  plugins: [ 
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js',
        minChunks: Infinity,
      }),

      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'app-manifest.json',
        basePath: '/'
      }),
      new ChunkManifestPlugin({
        filename: "manifest.json",
        manifestVariable: "webpackManifest"
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new CompressionPlugin({
          asset: "[path].gz[query]",
          algorithm: "gzip",
          test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
          threshold: 10240,
          minRatio: 0.8
      })
    ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Test: js & jsx
      {
        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      // Test: html
      {
        test: "\.html$",

        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              /* ... */
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
      // Test: css
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap',
      }, 
      // Test: url
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }, 
      // Test: json
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` options to name your file to 'vendor.js'. Remove that filename option or set a value with a hash:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  filename: 'vendor.js', // <====
  minChunks: Infinity,
}),
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble loading the hashed file into the app now, is there a plugin that will do that for me? or do I have to require the json output in my index.html?

Comment: [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)?

Comment: awesome! I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

You just check [this.](http://madole.xyz/asset-hashing-with-webpack/)

```
const vendorPackages = [  
    'jquery',
    'lodash',
    'fetch',
    'es6-promise'
];
const webpackConfig = {  
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/client/index.js',
        vendor: vendorPackages
    }
    //...
}
```